# Using local canonical form to approximate a curve (not necessarily unit speed)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

> Let $\alpha: I \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular curve with non vanishing curvature. Check that if $t_0 \in I$ is fixed, it's possible to choose a cartesian coordinate system and reparameterize the curve by it's arclength $s$ such that at a neighborhood of $t_0$, $\alpha$ is approximately of the form:
>
> $$\delta(s)=\left(s, \frac{k_0}{2}s^2,\frac{k_0 \tau_0}{6}s^3 \right)$$
>
> where $k_0$ and $\tau_0$ are the curvature and torsion of $\alpha$ at $t_0$.

Now, I know what the local canonical form of a unit speed curve is, but I couldn't reparameterize it to get to the form above (and I don't know why reparameterizing it would lead to a result even simpler).

**Edit**: If $\alpha$ was unit speed, then using the usual approach to approximating an unit speed curve:

$$\alpha(s) \approx \left(s - \frac{k^2(0)}{6}s^3,\frac{k(0)}{2} s^2 + \frac{k'(0)}{6}s^3, -\frac{k(0)\tau(0)}{6}s^3\right)$$

Since it's not, let $\beta(s)$ be the reparameterization required, then:

$$\alpha(\beta(s)) \approx \alpha(\beta(0)) + (\alpha(\beta(0)))'s + (\alpha(\beta(0)))''\frac{s^2}{2} + (\alpha(\beta(0)))'''\frac{s^3}{6}$$

but that isn't very helpful. How can I proceed?

Comment: Your title says not necessarily unit speed, but the question explicitly states arclength-parameterized - which is it?

Comment: The curve is not necessarily unit speed, I must reparameterize it so that it is.

Comment: Hopefully you know the result that every regular curve has a unit speed reparametrization? So this is no obstacle; just say $\beta$ is the unit speed reparametrization and proceed.

Comment: I do know that result... though I've been trying to work with that to get $\alpha$ into the form above, but haven't been able to.

Comment: Well, you need to work out what the correct coordinate frame is. Depending on what you've learnt already you may be able to guess it immediately; but you should be able to work it out systematically. Hopefully the choice of origin should be obvious - to get started finding the basis vectors, think about what the fact $\delta'(0) = (1,0,0)$ tells you about the coordinate frame.

Comment: I should choose $N(0) = (0,1,0)& and $B(0)=(0,0,1)$, right?